# My mesh is not showing in the viewport anymore

Tags: mesh

[image]I am a beginner and somehow got into a mode where my mesh has been replaced by a bounding box. You can see the mesh in the render but when I go back to object and edit modes all I can see is a rectangular bounding box where the mesh should be. I toggled through the various shading setting and can't seem to get it to come back.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it may be because you're displaying your object as Bounds, but please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: That was it. It took me a while to find where to turn it back to solid so I have no idea how it happened to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying your object as *Bounds*, switch to *Solid*:

[image]